# Android Framework read External Storage file

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I would read a file contents from external storage in android frameworks .

```
File file = new File(archiveFilePath);
if(file == null ) {return false;} 

if(!(file.canRead())){
    Log.e(TAG,"FILE can not have read permissions");
    return false;
}
```

When I set `archiveFilePath` to `/mnt/sdcard/temp.txt`,the program prints *"FILE can not have read permissions"* log information. But when i set `archiveFilePath` to `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/temp.txt`,the program can read file.

It happens in android 4.4.2.

Does anyone know what is happening and why?

Comment: Are you working on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Do you have read external storage permission as in android 4.4 its required to access external storage. see this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Comment: I working on a real devices

Comment: The program is working  on Android 4.2.2

Comment: @himanshumunjal Thank you for you answer. But you give links is effective for app,not framworks